# How to draw responsive bar chart that takes values from a textarea ( using D3 library)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, textarea, bar-chart

Trying to draw a responsive bar chart using D3.js that takes values from a HTML textarea element - just like it looks in the image below. If I enter a new value in the textarea and click outside the textarea, the bar chart should update with the new/modified bar. Struggling to connect the bar chart with the textarea.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code, please add a [mre] to your answer, not just an image. See also [ask]